# How to pass key-value pair from jsp to servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, key-value

I have a faculty entity,subject and mark entity. Every faculty has a list of preliminary subjects.

When entrant wants to apply for some faculty he should enter his marks in preliminary subjects and marks from his school diploma  (college, whatever).

And I want to be able to get this values as `key-value` pair like `subject-mark`.

So for now I'm passing to `apply.jsp` page two `List<Subject>` as a request attributes. One `List` contains  `all subjects` - this is for diploma, and another `List` contains `faculty subjects` - they are preliminary.

My `apply.jsp` page listed below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Apply for ${faculty.name}</title>
</head>
<body>
    You are in client apply for faculty view!

    <h1>${name}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><label>Faculty name: </label> <c:out value="${name}"></c:out></li>
        <li><label>Total seats: </label> <c:out value="${total_seats}"></c:out></li>
        <li><label>Budget seats: </label> <c:out value="${budget_seats}"></c:out></li>
    </ul>

    <form action="controller" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="applyFaculty" /> <input
            type="hidden" name="show" value="false" /> <input type="hidden"
            name="facultySubjects" value="${facultySubjects}" /> <input
            type="hidden" name="allSubjects" value="${allSubjects}" />

        <h1>Your preliminary marks</h1>

        <table id="preliminary">

            <c:forEach var="facultySubject" items="${facultySubjects}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${facultySubject.name}">${facultySubject.name}</c:out>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="preliminaryMark" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>

        <h1>Your diploma marks</h1>

        <table id="diploma">

            <c:forEach var="subject" items="${allSubjects}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${subject.id}">${subject.name}</c:out></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="diplomaMark" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="OK">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So how should I transform it to achieve needed functionality ?

PS. if it's simpler to do - actually i need to know only `Subject` `id` field to make needed `insert` in database.

Comment: @Amrola edit your comment please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try something like the following :

```
<c:forEach var="facultySubject" items="${facultySubjects}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${facultySubject.name}">${facultySubject.name}</c:out>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="subject_${facultySubject.id}" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

and in your servlet do the following :

```
 Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
for (String key: parameterMap.keySet()) {
    if (key.startsWith("subject_")) {
       // do what ever you want here 
    }
}
```

Hope that Helps .

Answer (score 1):

Amrola came with idea, which I think is really good.

In this answer I'm going to add my code example which meets a bit more to my purposes.

So `apply.jsp` looks like:

```
<form action="controller" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="applyFaculty" />
        <input type="hidden" name="facultyId" value="${id}" /><input
            type="hidden" name="show" value="false" />

        <h1>Your preliminary marks</h1>

        <table id="preliminary">

            <c:forEach var="facultySubject" items="${facultySubjects}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${facultySubject.name}">${facultySubject.name}</c:out>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="${facultySubject.id}_preliminary" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

        </table>

        <h1>Your diploma marks</h1>

        <table id="diploma">

            <c:forEach var="subject" items="${allSubjects}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${subject.name}">${subject.name}</c:out>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="${subject.id}_diploma" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="OK">
        </p>
    </form>
```

And in my servlet I'm working in the next way:

```
Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
            for (String parameterName : parameterMap.keySet()) {

            if (parameterName.endsWith("preliminary")
                    || parameterName.endsWith("diploma")) {
                String[] value = parameterMap.get(parameterName);
                Byte markValue = Byte.valueOf(value[0]);
                String[] subjectIdAndExamType = parameterName
                        .split("_");

                Integer subjectId = Integer
                        .valueOf(subjectIdAndExamType[0]);
                String examType = subjectIdAndExamType[1];

                Mark mark = new Mark(subjectId, entrant.getId(),
                        markValue, examType);
                ...// another logic
```

So to sum up - from the next lines:

```
<input type="text" name="${facultySubject.id}_preliminary" value="" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="${subject.id}_diploma" value="" />
```

In a servlet I have:

1. Subject id
2. Exam type
3. Mark value

So for your's problems you can use any combination of parameters in `name` attribute and then just extract them in your servlet by specified regex.